# heist template new api

Tags: haskell, heist

Which's the equivalent for

```
...
import Happstack.Server.Heist

pageHeist :: B.ByteString -> [(T.Text,T.Text)] -> ServerPart Response
kfzPaginaHeist template par = do
       pagina <- newTemplateDirectory' "template" $ bindStrings par defaultHeistState       
       render pagina template
```

with the new heist api? Also, did the  and  (or the way you're supposed to load templates) change?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you probably don't want to call newTemplateDirectory in the ServerPart monad.  It should be called when your application starts up.  Second, instead of passing it a HeistState, now you pass it a HeistConfig which contains all of your splices.

Comment: yes, happstack uses heist.compiled so should I use compiled splices? And if yes, I have to pass hcCompiledSplices and hcTemplates int the HeistConfig?

Comment: Yes, and yes.  You can also pass in interpreted splices if you want.  They just won't be used.

Comment: I changed it to http://hpaste.org/84284. The splices work correctly, but all <apply> and <bind> don't work anymore (template applied:http://goo.gl/YnjNq and with apply: http://goo.gl/ktgFL ). Could you please tell me why?

Comment: You have to add those splices as well.  They are you supplied for you in [this list](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/heist/0.11.1/doc/html/Heist.html#v:defaultInterpretedSplices).

Comment: Thank you! Now everything is fine